# How to close ion-select programmatically

Tags: reactjs, ionic5, ion-select

In my ionic react app, I am using IonSelect in a form. I need to close the IonSelect dropdown programmatically inside a hardware back button event listener call when the dropdown is open. Here is the code

```
export const SingleSelection: React.FC = () => { 
   const [gender, setGender] = useState<string>();
   
    useEffect(() => {
     
      document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev: any) => {
         ev.detail.register(1000, async (processNextHandler: any) => {
           console.log('Handler B was called!');
    
           processNextHandler();
         });
      });
      return () => {
        console.log("use effect return");
      }
   }, [])

   return (
     <IonPage>
        <IonContent>
          <IonItem>
              <IonLabel>Gender</IonLabel>
              <IonSelect value={gender} placeholder="Select One" onIonChange={e => setGender(e.detail.value)}>
                 <IonSelectOption value="female">Female</IonSelectOption>
                 <IonSelectOption value="male">Male</IonSelectOption>
               </IonSelect>
           </IonItem>
         </IonContent>
      </IonPage>   
    );
};
```

**UPDATED: [solved]:**  here is my updated complete code with modal. Inside the hardware back button event listener method first the ion select is closed (if it kept open) and then the modal is closed

```
const ModalExample: React.FC = () => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const [gender, setGender] = useState<string>();

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev: any) => {
            ev.detail.register(1000, async (processNextHandler: any) => {
                console.log('Handler B was called!');
                try {
                    console.log("close ion select");
                    const alert = await alertController.getTop();
                    if (alert) {
                        alert.dismiss();
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log("close modal")
                    const element = await modalController.getTop();
                    if (element) {
                        //element.dismiss();
                        setShowModal(false)
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                processNextHandler();
            });
        });
        return () => {
            console.log("use effect return");
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <IonContent>
            <IonModal isOpen={showModal} cssClass='my-custom-class'>
                <p>This is modal content</p>
                <IonItem>
                    <IonLabel>Gender</IonLabel>
                    <IonSelect value={gender} placeholder="Select One" onIonChange={e => setGender(e.detail.value)}>
                        <IonSelectOption value="female">Female</IonSelectOption>
                        <IonSelectOption value="male">Male</IonSelectOption>
                    </IonSelect>
                </IonItem>
                <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Close Modal</IonButton>
            </IonModal>
            <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Show Modal</IonButton>
        </IonContent>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the solution. Using `alertController` IonSelect dropdown can be closed programmatically,

```
import { alertController } from "@ionic/core";
.....

useEffect(() => {

    document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev: any) => {
      ev.detail.register(1005, async (processNextHandler: any) => {
        console.log('Handler D was called!');
        const alert = await alertController.getTop();
        console.log(alert);
        if (alert) {
          alert.dismiss();
          return;
        }
        processNextHandler();
      });
    });
    return () => {
      console.log("use effect return");
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although pressing the hardware back button automatically closes the IonSelect dropdown. If that doesn't work for you, here is a work-around using `useRef` hook:

```
export const SingleSelection: React.FC = () => { 
    const [gender, setGender] = useState<string>();
    const selectRef = useRef<any>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
     
      document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev: any) => {
         ev.preventDefault(); // TO PREVENT THE CLOSING OF MODAL
         ev.detail.register(1000, async (processNextHandler: any) => {
           console.log('Handler B was called!');
           selectRef.current.close() // SEE HERE


           // HERE YOU CAN NOW CLOSE THE MODAL

           processNextHandler();
         });
      });
      return () => {
        console.log("use effect return");
      }
   }, [])

    return (
         ...
         <IonSelect ref={(ref: any) => selectRef.current = ref} value={gender} placeholder="Select One" onIonChange={e => setGender(e.detail.value)}>
            <IonSelectOption value="female">Female</IonSelectOption>
            <IonSelectOption value="male">Male</IonSelectOption>
         </IonSelect>
         ....
    
        );

};
```

Comment: `TypeError: selectRef.current.close is not a function`  showing this error

Comment: `...hardware back button automatically closes the IonSelect dropdown`  , yes you are right,  But my dropdown is on a modal and using hardware back button I close the modal but the dropdown kept open, So I have to close it too programmetically

Comment: try adding `ev.preventDefault()` first, as the current ref might not be available after the modal is closed

Comment: I have to close the dropdown before closing the modal and accordingly I tried with `selectRef.current.close()` , but an error is shown `TypeError: selectRef.current.close is not a function`, probably IonSelect have no function called `close`

Comment: Yes that is why i am asking you to add `ev.preventDefault()` so it stops the closing of your modal on back button press, then you can close the ion-select. This is beacuse if the modal is closed first then `selectRef` would be undefined that is why the function is coming undefined.

Comment: I close the modal programmatically with the back button press.

Comment: After closing the select you can close the modal too.

Comment: yes, first I close the ion select programmatically and then close the modal too. I test your code for closing the ion select accordingly, then the error appears, cause most likely ion select doesn't have `close()` method

Comment: You're not getting my point, check my updated answer

Comment: yes, I close my modal exactly there   `const element = await modalController.getTop(); if (element) { element.dismiss(); return; }`

Comment: You don't have to do  that, that's what i am saying. First you need to close the ionSelect then you can close modal. Modal should not be closed before ionSelect Alert.

Comment: I have updated the code, have a look please

Answer (score 0):

in ionic 7 if you use interface popover

```
constructor(private popoverController: PopoverController) {}
closeSelect(){
if (this.popoverController && await this.popoverController.getTop()) {
  await this.popoverController.dismiss();
}
}
```